# Need Help Creating Linux Script

Tags: linux, if-statement, command-line, replace

I have the following:

```
...
#define DIRT 4
#define PLANKS 5
#define WOOD_PLANKSs 5
#define BRICKS 6
...
```

I need to remove one of the lines that have the same number as the line before them (Ex. Remove planks because woodplanks has the same number, 5).

Is there a method to do this in a linux (or Windows) script, perhaps using an if then statement?

Comment: Is your file composed ONLY of "define" entries, or are they other lines in the file? And are the duplicate entries always consecutive?

Comment: Duplicate values are always consecutive, and it ONLY is composed of #define NAME #

Comment: Then go for carlpett's solution ;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Linux, use the `uniq` command, and the `-f` parameter to skip comparing the first two fields: `uniq -f 2 <your-file>`

Comment: So if I wanted to delete the WOOD_PLANKS line in file.txt then what would I use?

Comment: The above command would remove `WOOD_PLANKS` (as well as any other row with a repeated third column) by issuing `uniq -f 2 file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Create a awk script called removeDup.awk as

```
  1 BEGIN      { lastDefine=""
  2            }
  3 /^#define/ { if (lastDefine=="") {
  4                lastDefine=$3
  5              } else {
  6                if (lastDefine==$3) {
  7                  next
  8                } else {
  9                  lastDefine=$3
 10                }
 11              }
 12            }
 13            { print
 14            }
```

awk -f removeDup.awk filename

Comment: Well, that looks like the solution I was about to post, and that would have been required if the file might have contained other non-define lines. +1 for the effort ;)

Comment: I will try this when I have acess to a linux computer or can find an online shell.